# How to hide customer grid in admin according to different role in magento

Tags: magento

I want to hide customer list for one role user in magento admin. Here i want to display all columns to filter and display only filtered record.
For example: 
1) Role A, user A in role A
2) When admin user login then he can only see manage customer only with search columns.
3) If user enter email and search then all record according to entered email.
4) If another admin user login then he can see all details as usual.

I am thinking to do this by checking role id but don't know in which file i can implement it. as I can find its grid

If any one have solution or how to do this then please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using ACL rules you could show or hide the whole grid on a per-role basis. If you want to show different content on the grid, you would need to override the Grid Block, and put some conditionals... but will be a bit hacky.

Comment: Thanks Javier. Can you please describe how can I use ACL rules ? I can understand we can assign resources to particular role. is it more different then that ? please explore your answer.

Comment: Basically you can configure the permissions from the admin: System -> Permissions -> Roles -> Add / Edit Role, and for instance uncheck the customer grid for a particular role to prevent them from accessing it. For creating your own ACL roles in your custom extension check for instance http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/10/28/defining-acl-resources-custom-and-admin-menu-in-magento.html

Comment: @Thanks Javier . But i already mentioned in my comment like I know we can assign permission in role. But I don't want to add new menu item. And we have manage customer resource available in permissions. I can check manage customer checkbox for role by this user can see customer list. Now i would like to show only column names with search option. If user search any then only he can see record.                                                                                                        May be i am not understanding your answer if it matching with my issue :(  it seems different.